# Building c# classes using assert test conditions

Tags: c#

What should I do or how am i supposed to declare MyClass for this assert to be true

```
Assert.AreSame(typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("ToString").DeclaringType, typeof(MyClass))
```

Comment: Is this something you actually need to test?

Comment: What are you trying to test here?

Comment: Simply override `ToString` in `MyClass`? What is the real question here? Did you try anything? Did it work?

Comment: this is a resharper guide to check wether i have declared a class correctly

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i havent tried anything because i have failed to grasp how its supposed to work, when i run the test based on this class it fails, if i change Assert.AreSame to AreNotSame test is a success

Comment: "On this class", since you haven't posted your class it is impossible for us to tell you why that is(n't).

Comment: Its probably an exam/coursework question, hence no code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to override the [ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) method in your MyClass declaration.

```
class MyClass
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "MyClass";
    }
}
```

**Explaination:**

The reason overriding ToString allows the assertion to pass is because the assert determines the Type in which the ToString method is declared (which is System.Object by default). By overriding the method, you redeclare the ToString method in your MyClass.

**Alternative**

Instead of overriding you could use the `new` keyword. This will redeclare a method without overriding it. The diffrence being that when an instance `MyClass` is casted to an `object` calling `ToString` on it will not call your method decorated with the `new` keyword, but it would when decorated with the `override` keyword.

```
class MyClass
{
    public new string ToString()
    {
        return "MyClass";
    }
}
```

Comment: the test passed using the override, is there any other way than to override

Comment: @ngoni I added an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

In this test you are triyng to get the DeclaringType of ToString(). But your Class does not declare "ToString" so the DeclaringType will always return "object" (the base class wich declares ToString())

One way to avoid this, is to use the ReflectedType property instead of DeclaringType.

```
Assert.AreSame(typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("ToString").ReflectedType,typeof(MyClass);
```

you'll obtain the same result if you declare "MyClass" this way, overriding ToString(), and use the original test, using DeclaringType property!

```
class MyClass
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
       return "Foo";
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!